# How to display a different sidebar for all blog posts and on the page where the blogs are listing?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site which have 4 pages with one page is a blog page.
I have created a page template for the blog page to display all blogs on this page.
On this page template I am displaying the different sidebar from the other pages.
This sidebar displaying the blog archives.

But when I click on an archive the sidebar changes to the that first sidebar which is also on another pages.

How will I remain this second sidebar to be display on every blog post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of custom pages, for example, we are having aboutus.php having body contents like this:

```
  <?php
  /**
   * Template Name: About us
   *
   * Selectable from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
   */
  ?>
  <?php get_header(); ?>

     //body content for aboutus page

  <?php include ('aboutus_sidebar.php'); ?>//separate sidebar for aboutus
  <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then, create a file named aboutus_sidebar.php with whatever you want.